# Grails shell doesn't recompile changed files

Tags: shell, grails, groovy, static-methods, recompile

I'm new to grails and came across an issue of grails shell not recompiling my classes even though displaying a message about it. Here is what I'm doing:

1. I have a grails 2.0.0 app that has class with certain static methods
2. I would like to test some of the functionality from grails shell, so I go ahead and launch it from the grails project folder as `grails
   shell`
3. I'm calling a static method of the class to perform some work as follows:

   ```
   import com.mypackage.*
   MyClass.doWork()
   ```
4. If I'm seeing some unexpected behavior or runtime error I'm modifying the source code accordingly and grails shell shows it actually is seeing the change: `|Compiling 2 source files.`
5. Then I run the method, but it's seems that the method is the same, because it gives me same error even though I'm sure I've saved the groovy file.
6. So, I have to `exit` the shell and launch it again. Then grails picks up the changes.

What I'm doing wrong? It seems to be rather weird expected behavior...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Only `run-app` enables reloading by default. Run `grails -reloading shell` to reload changed files. I'd use the console though - it's way more user-friendly: `grails -reloading console`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I didn't think about it this way.